transforme an emission map into a color map
Okay this sounds a little bit crazy, but, with some researches, I found a node group how is able to localise sharp edges and it work awesome ! Here is the node group

And here is the result

I needed to switch the color to apply some shader stuff, so I tried a color map. But that doesn't seem to work well.

So I put a gamma modificater, turned it up and burned my eyes up.

And then I understand. The white is not a color but it's light from haven! So I imagine that the map is not a color map but an emissive map.
So now the question : how can I turn an emissive map into a color map ?
Have a nice day !

Why do you mean "that doesn't seem to work well" ? In your 3rd image, the result of your Color Ramp is as expected. It would also help a lot if you can upload your file with https://blend-exchange.com/ and update your question with it.

The problem with your setup is, this "sharp edges" group has an output range of 3.2 to -0.1. The Color Ramp only accepts an input range of 0 to 1, so everything below 0 down to -0.1 that gets in there is clamped to 0, everything from 1 to 3.2 is clamped to 1. Apart from that the Color Ramp has a Color output, which means the result is affected by the Color Management, I guess that's the reason why the white is only light grey. Stupid question: why use a Color Ramp? Just switch the output values of the Map Range node to To Min = -0.1 and To Max = 3.2 for example.

...and I am not sure what you mean with "the map is not a color map but an emissive map". If you mean by "map" the output of the "sharp edges" frame, no it is not emissive. It only becomes emissive if you either plug it into an Emission input of a Principled BSDF, an Emission shader or directly into the Material Output. But the same is true for the Color Ramp output. The difference is as mentioned before, the Color Ramp is limited to 1, while the Map Range gives a maximum of 3.2, so it is three times brighter.
